# Commit changes to another repo

Tags: mercurial, commit, tortoisehg

I use two mercurial repositories, one for the current stable version and one for new development.  I accidentally developed a new feature inside the current stable repo and now I want to commit the changes to the new dev repo and *not* to the current stable repo.  Is there a way to do this?  I have not committed any of my changes yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
hg diff >changes.patch
```

To create a patch of your changes. Then, go in the other repo, update where you need your changes to be, and issue

```
hg import --no-commit changes.patch
```

With the proper folder to `changes.patch` You should then be at the same place you were on the other repo, too.

However, if both repos are equivalent, whether you commit and push your changes from the current repo or the other, they could eventually be replicated on both, so think about the necessity of moving the changes across repos. Use branches to handle different feature development.

Comment: Very nice and very clean solution. +1 from me. I was thinking something along the lines of `commit`ing the change in the stable repo, `push`ing it to development, and then using `backout` in the stable repo. The only negative issue I could see with my solution is polluting the history with negating commits. Your solution is much more cleaner however.